# display :inline-block is not working without DOCTYPE in IE

Tags: html, css

I want a data block whose width and height must be adjusted to inside content of the data block automatically.I did it by putting content  inside a DIV tag whose *display* style as **inline-block**. Its working fine in all browsers if DOCTYPE tag is present. If DOCTYPE is not there,It not working in IE(The div width is adjusted to width of the browser).But it works in other browsers. Is there any solution or any alternative.... ? Can any body please help me....

Here is my piece of code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <style>
   .MultiSelectMenu{
     border:1px solid black;
     display:inline-block;
    }
   .MultiSelectMenu ul{
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
   }
  .MultiSelectMenu ul li{
    list-style:none;
    background:#abc4c9;
    border-bottom:1px solid #354e53;
    padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div class="MultiSelectMenu" >
     <ul>
       <li>Telugu</li>
       <li>Hindi</li>
       <li>English</li>
       <li>Marathi</li>
       <li>Kannada</li>
       <li>Malayalam</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see your problem. EVERY page should have a DOCTYPE

Comment: You need a `Doctype` to be [HTML compliant](http://validator.w3.org/).  And you never explained why you'd want to remove it.

Comment: Just add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to your page. It HAS to be there and I can't see a reason why you want to omit it.

Comment: Guys...I have to use this code in my SAP application. There I cannot add <!DOCTYPE> tag, that is a restriction. So I hope you got my prob now.Let me know the solution please without DOCTYPE.

Comment: @SivaCharan, you are not supposed to include the `html`, `head`, or `body` tags in the HTML frame of jsFiddle because it takes care of all this for you.  See the `doctype` in the source code of [this page](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/hzEMf/show/)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
   .MultiSelectMenu { float: left; }
```

and set `clear: left` on the element right after the `div` element.

Answer (score 1):

you can add Left Float to the .MultiSelectMenu and when you are done with the divs.. add empty div just after the closing tag of the last .MultiSelectMenu div that has clear:both or left style to clear the divs floats.

for eg:

```
.clear {
  clear:both; // or left
}
```

html:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```